# What protocol used in Android NSD?

Tags: android

There is Network Service Discovery (NSD) in Android API 16+.

What RFC or other document describes this protocol? 
Is there any compatible implementations on other platforms (iPhone, WP8)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's [Bonjour / Zeroconf](http://www.dns-sd.org/). Specifically [DNSSD](http://www.dns-sd.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It specifically uses Multicast DNS - http://www.multicastdns.org/

You can see that by running a packet sniffer such as Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) on a machine on the same network and filtering for mdns (note that mdns filtering requires a recent version of Wireshark).

It's the same standard that's also powering auto-discovery on MacOS / iOS, Bonjour, as well as on Linux, Avahi; you can use it to discover Apple or Avahi services just as well as services on other Android devices, and vice versa.

Comment: This answer is more useful to me since not only it specifies that it uses DNSSD but also points out that the DNSSD is implemented using multicast as opposed to unicast.